# batch file will not set permissions and get input from command line

Tags: command-line, batch-file, permissions, dos

The code below is to run through a folder which contains several files (ending "*_perms.txt") which defines the permissions of directories, based on that user name. Ideally the code will at some point remove the directory and extension to just use the name of the .txt files as the user.

For now the code works by iterating through the files; asking what the permission user name is; followed by the permission level; then iterating through the listed directories in the file setting the permissions.

Except it doesn't.

When I run the file and enter the user and level it doesn't seem to acknowledge what was entered, but instead uses the last entered values from the previous run (for all).

I'm a complete n00b to batch so please forgive any outstanding coding errors or practices. Also any other advice around the code would be very much appreciated.

```
:: Get the files which define the permissions
FOR /R %perms% %%i IN ("*_perms.txt") DO (
echo %%i

:: TO-DO - remove path and file extension
echo ++++ %%i Folder ++++ >> %logFile% & echo.
SET /P permUser=:Enter the user. 
SET /P permType=:Enter the user access right. 

:: Set the permissions for the folders specified
FOR /F %%j IN (%%i) DO (
    ::echo %%j  
    ::echo %permUser%
    echo %VSS_home%\%%j

    :: N.B - uses the last entered parameter on the command-line. 
    ::       also does not get recorded onto log file. 
    net share permDir=%VSS_home%\%%j /grant:%permUser%,%permType% /users:%MaxUsers% /remark:%%j >> %logFile%
    echo User: %permUser%, Rights: %permType% >> %logFile%
)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, see [this discussion](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4204) about using `::` label comments within parentheses. Basically, do not use them, use `rem`!

**Second**, see [Delayed Expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for how variables get set within parentheses.  Basically, you need `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` if you are going to access variables that you are setting within parentheses.

Here are some good posts that explain how Batch files get processed.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7970912/891976

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/891976

**Great Batch References**

[SS64](http://ss64.com/),
[DosTips](http://www.dostips.com/),
[ComputerHope](http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php/board,2.0.html),
[Rob van der Woude](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/),
[TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772390(v=ws.10).aspx)